# Is it possible to use GHC.Stack.HasCallStack in a typeclass declaration and/or instantiation?

Tags: haskell

Let's say I have this typeclass:

```
import GHC.Stack

class Foo a where
  foo :: a
instance Foo Int where
  foo = undefined
```

How can I add the HasCallStack constraint to the `foo` value? I've tried like this:

```
class (HasCallStack) => Foo a where
  foo :: a
instance (HasCallStack) => Foo Int where
  foo = undefined
```

And I get a type error like:

```
source.hs:10:1: error:
    • Illegal implicit parameter ‘?callStack::CallStack’
    • In the context: HasCallStack
      While checking the super-classes of class ‘Foo’
      In the class declaration for ‘Foo’
```

I've also tried only having the constraints on either the class or the instance. I got similar errors in both cases.

Is this possible somehow? Or is it impossible to get call stacks for class members?  It would help me debug something quite a bit more easily at the moment if it was possible somehow to get the call stack.

Comment: What if you remove it from the `class`? Since there there is no `a` at all in the "head" of the type constraint.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You only need a the stack at the call site of `foo`, so this compiles, and I believe it will propagate the implicit as expected:

```
class Foo a where
    foo :: HasCallStack => a
```